# How to save to a file? Using AS3 on iOS (beginner)

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, file

I am trying to save a single word to a file, then read that word to confirm success. When the code to read the file is run, it returns no data. And, I am not able to verify that any file is created.

Here is the code:

```
// This is run at the beginning of the frame, and this does display Hello in a textArea

var str:String = "Hello\n";
feedback.text = str;



// This is run when the user taps a button

var myFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("./eFiveV3/text.txt");

var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();


fileStream.open(myFile,FileMode.WRITE);

fileStream.writeUTF(str);

fileStream.close();

str = "Goodbye\n";


// if the code below is run, then the feedback box will be empty. if the code below is commented out, then the feedback box will contain the text: Goodbye

fileStream.open(myFile,FileMode.READ);

str = fileStream.readMultiByte(myFile.size,File.systemCh arset);

fileStream.close();

feedback.text = str;
```

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

I would try a couple diagnostic things, but I can wager a guess why you are seeing that problem.

But first, I would try setting `feedback.text` to `myFile.size.toString()` and see if it says there are any bytes at all in the file. If that comes back with something > 0 then I would wager that the following is going on:

You are using `writeUTF()` when writing the string, but you are using `readMultiByte()` when reading the string back in. When you use `writeUTF()` it doesn't just write the string to the file directly, it prepends the stream with the length of the string (as a 16 bit integer), where as `readMultiByte()` is trying to coerce those bytes directly into a string with the given charset. Those extra bytes at the beginning might be causing `readMultiByte()` to fail or screw up (it would be trying to read `0x06,0x00,0x00,0x00,H,e,l,l,o,\n` rather than just `H,e,l,l,o,\n`). `writeUTF()` can be used to write multiple strings to the same file, and then read them back out of the stream with `readUTF()`.

You probably want to pair your read and write methods correct, either use `writeUTF()` and `readUTF()` or use `writeMultiByte()` and `readMultiByte()`. If you are trying to write a pure text file, then `writeMultiByte()` is going to the be the way to go. If you are trying to serialize a bunch of different data into a single file, then `writeUTF()` is the way to go.

If the file size is in fact zero, then I'll have to dig a little more and see whats going on.

Comment: Thank-you very much. I tried switching to readUTF and it worked the first time. And, your explanation was very helpful too. I am very new to using ActionScript and still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code with some event listeners that verify when the file has been written and read.

```
function saveFile():void{  

    var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("text.txt");

    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  

    fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.WRITE);  
    fileStream.writeUTFBytes("Hi this file was saved from AIR application without dialog");  
    fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
    fileStream.close();  

    function fileClosed(event:Event):void { 

        trace("File Saved");  

    }        
}  

function readFile():void{  

    var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("text.txt");

    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  

    fileStream.openAsync(file, FileMode.READ);  
    var str:String = fileStream.readMultiByte(file.size,File.systemCharset);
    fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
    fileStream.close();  

    function fileClosed(event:Event):void { 

        trace("File Contents:" + str);  

    }        
} 

saveFile();

readFile();
```

Don't thank me, thank Ray: [source](http://askmeflash.com/qdetail/440/save-file-locally-in-flash-actionscript-3-without-displaying-dialog)